# undelete 1 file from ext4 on LVM on LUKS

Tags: lvm, ext4, luks, extundelete

### summary

How to (relatively painlessly and reliably) {restore, undelete} a file from an ext4 filesystem inside a LVM volume inside a LUKS container, given one knows the fully-qualified path to the file before it was deleted? (Apologies in advance if I'm using incorrect terms--please correct where necessary.)

### details

The good news is, it's been years since I accidentally deleted a file that I couldn't easily restore (e.g., from backup). Define some terms for exactness:

- call the file I {deleted, seek to restore} the `target file`
- call the directory/folder in which the target file formerly resided the `target dir`
- call the partition {on which the target file formerly resided, to which I seek to restore the target file} the `target partition`

The bad news is,

- The last time, the target partition was "simple ext4": i.e., no encryption or other management.
- This time, the target partition is the one with name=`LVM2_crypt-home` from the following `lsblk` table:

  ```
  NAME                  MAJ:MIN   SIZE  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
  sda                     8:0   465.8G  disk
  ├─sda1                  8:1    16.6G  part
  ├─sda2                  8:2    97.7G  part
  ├─sda3                  8:3     500M  part  /boot
  ├─sda4                  8:4       1K  part
  └─sda5                  8:5     351G  part
    └─LVM2_crypt        254:0     351G  crypt
      ├─LVM2_crypt-swap 254:1     3.9G  lvm
      ├─LVM2_crypt-root 254:2      20G  lvm   /
      └─LVM2_crypt-home 254:3   327.1G  lvm   /home
  ```

I believe I recall how to recover a file from a simple partition using [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/): see procedure below. What I'd like to know is

1. Will the same or similar procedure work for a managed+encrypted partition? If not same, what needs added, modified, or deleted?
2. Is there a more reliable tool (than `extundelete`) for this usecase? If so, what is its procedure for this usecase?

#### simple-partition procedure

My procedure last time--for the "simple" ext4 partition--used `extundelete` like the following (bash) example:

1. Read `info extundelete` and (the all-too-meager) [extundelete doc](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) (scroll down to heading=`Documentation`). Note that it can handle usecases other than that illustrated here, e.g., restore *all* deleted files from a partition.
2. Specify the target file:

   1. define its fully-qualified path `TARGET_FQP`, remembering **not** to use `~`:

      ```
      # CHANGE FOR YOUR USECASE!
      TARGET_FQP="${HOME}/video/greatest_movie_ever.mp4"
      echo "TARGET_FQP='${TARGET_FQP}'"
      ```
   2. define its directory/folder (which we'll assume is on the same (target) partition as the target file):

      ```
      TARGET_DIR="$(dirname "${TARGET_FQP}")"
      echo "TARGET_DIR='${TARGET_DIR}'"
      ```
   3. define its filename (for use below)

      ```
      TARGET_FN="$(basename "${TARGET_FQP}")"
      echo "TARGET_FN='${TARGET_FN}'"
      ```
3. Identify the target partition `TARGET_PART` and its mount point `TARGET_MP` from your target dir:

   ```
   TARGET_PART="$(df --output=source "${TARGET_FQP}" | tail -1)"
   echo "TARGET_PART='${TARGET_PART}'"
   TARGET_MP="$(df --output=target "${TARGET_FQP}" | tail -1)"
   echo "TARGET_MP='${TARGET_MP}'"
   ```
4. Open your shell of choice (in your terminal of choice) with a current working directory (CWD) such that

   - CWD is on a partition other than the target. (Get information about your partitions using `lsblk`, `fdisk` or your tool of choice.)
   - `extundelete` will restore any file it finds (if any) to a CWD subdir name=`RECOVERED_FILES`, so I'm guessing that, if you already have one with that name, you want to move it. (If you know how to override that, please lemme know. IIRC, `--restore-directory` does *not* do this.)
5. Remount the target partition read-only:

   ```
   mount --options remount,ro --source "${TARGET_PART}"
   ```
6. Run `extundelete`:

   ```
   date # because if this runs too long, you'll wanna give up
   extundelete --restore-file "${TARGET_FQP}" "${TARGET_PART}"
   ```
7. Check the restored file:

   ```
   SAVED_RELPATH="./RECOVERED_FILES/${TARGET_FN}"
   echo '(hopefully) restored file @'
   ls -al "${SAVED_RELPATH}"
   ```
8. Presuming the restored file @ `SAVED_RELPATH` is what you want, you can either remount `TARGET_PART` read/write and move it there, or (what I usually do)

   1. move the restored file to an external backup
   2. reboot the PC containing `TARGET_PART`
   3. copy the restored file from the backup to `TARGET_DIR`

Your corrections or improvements are welcome.

Comment: Have you succeeded?

Comment: @petRUShka I think `extundelete` or `ext4magic` may work